# Netgear Router Port Forwarding corrupt after updating

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding

I just updated the firmware on the WNR1000v3 router. However all the port forwarding configs that were set up previously have become "ghosts". They do not show up on the list nor work, but I cannot add a new entry.

Entry before adding:
[image]

Error after adding: [image]

Comment: Did you try factory resetting it?

Comment: Make that an answer :) ... why cant netgear make their update better...

Comment: @agz be better if they did make it better but if you didn't even consider a factory reset then that's a PEBCAK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Factory reset would put your device back to it's original settings, which would probably fix this.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, your only option is to do a full reset and re-enter your config.  It's best to do this anyway as you don't know what else might be corrupted internally.

I know it's a bit stable-door-after-horse, but all the Netgear devices I've seen have the ability to save a backup of the config, so perhaps it would be worth doing this before your next upgrade.

Comment: Netgear actually makes this suggestion before you agree to install the update.  Although it begs the question, if nothing was not working, why even upgrade the firmware?

Comment: Perhaps the new version adds desirable features or fixes annoying bugs.

Comment: Of course that might be the case I was just raising the question itself.  Personally I only patch when security vulerabilities are found and it has served me well.

Comment: A commendable strategy :)

Comment: Sometimes software upgrades introduce new features or phase out obsolete ones, or a different config file format (as seems to be the case here) making an old software config incompatible with the new  firmware.  With SOHO equipment that are more likely to have tighter restrictions on binary sizes (thus be less likely to have extra code in them to parse the old into new).  I don't excuse them from working around these issues, but I can see how those inconveniences would come to be...